# MySQL: order by sum

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have article table

```
`id`,
`article_id`,
`stage_1_point`,
`stage_2_point`
```

I need top 10 articles based on

```
(stage_1_point+stage_2_point),
```

in the list and when i view any article i need to show its place.
My question is how can show its place without using order by.

Comment: You can use limit function.

Comment: i cant use limit i have to show all articles

Comment: who does vote down my guestion? its a problem and i asked it as i can try

Comment: You should read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE `ORDER BY (stage_1_point+stage_2_point) DESC`

So, It will be like

```
SELECT `id`,
`article_id`,
`stage_1_point`,
`stage_2_point`
FROM YOUR_TABLE ORDER BY (stage_1_point+stage_2_point) DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

**UPDATE**

As OP stated, he/she needs to know the position of specific article.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT `id`,
`article_id`,
`stage_1_point`,
`stage_2_point`,
 @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM YOUR_TABLE, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY      
(stage_1_point+stage_2_point) DESC) TAB
WHERE `article_id`=10
```

Above query will return rows for article_id 10, which will have a column `Rank` which tells the position of the article.

Comment: You haven't mentioned date column. Right ?

Comment: Then, how would you expect to order by date ? :s You should write everything clear. I think, that's why people downvoted to your question.

Comment: I would highly recommend to add your sample data and expected data and what you tried. This will definitely help everyone to understand your problem.

Comment: for example i view any article i need to know its place i cant use ordery by and limit i just select one row from table

Answer (score 0):

You can try below Query as below

```
Select 
    stage_1_point+stage_2_point as added_point,
    columnsid,
    article_id,
    stage_1_point,
    stage_2_point 
FROM tablename 
ORDER BY 1 desc 
Limit 0,10
```

This will sort data based on column one result and fetch top 10 results only.